# Generate Crystal Reports in windows c# for Multiple customer receipts

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I want to generates the receipts in windows `c#` application for multiple customers.
For example, If there are 5 customers in my database then it will generate 5 pages report, one page for each customer.

I saw many examples but only one page is displaying at a time, not able to generates all customers receipts.

Below code, I tried and it generates the one-page report but only for the last customer, I want to generate like if 10 customers then it should generate a 10-page report, one for each customer.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            int from = 1, to = 10;
            DataTable dt = dblayer.CustomerInfoRange(from,to);
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {

                customerReport1.SetParameterValue("pName", dr["Name"].ToString());
                customerReport1.SetParameterValue("pAddress", dr["Billing_Address"].ToString());
                crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = customerReport1;

            }

        }
```

Please help, how to generates the 10 pages reports one for each customer?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I did not see any mention of your Crystal Report .rpt file, where you design your report.

But what you should do, is enter the fields you want display on each page in the details section, Name and Address in your case. Then in Section Expert, select the Details Section, then Paging, there you have paging options such as

[image]

1. New Page Before: to add new page before each detail section
2. New Page After: to add new page after each detail section. You can also select End of Section or after a number of visible records